# wrong result in spatial data query sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008, geospatial, spatial

Im trying to get familiar with spatial data using sql server 2008.

I use book: http://www.beginningspatial.com/

and there is sample data: http://www.census.gov/geo/cob/bdy/zt/z500shp/zt06_d00_shp.zip

I uploaded it to my sql server database and Spatial results are presented well. Everything seems to be ok but when I tried to calculate distance between 2 geometries result is really small.

For example 0.27

The same is if I try to calculate STLength of given region. Result also is very small like 0.19 for example.

I wonder why the results are so small. I used SRID 4269 importing data.

Does anyone have any idea why is it like that ? I think that the result whould be in meters.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

STLength returns units in the data source's unit of measure.  In your case, you chose [SRID 4326](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/4326/), which stores the data in latitude/longitude, therefore your base units are a "degree", not a standard linear unit like feet/meters.  To calculate the distance in linear units, you should load your data as a projected format.

You might want to refer to this [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037354/sql-server-units-question), as well.